# Storing constants in tuple vs table

Tags: sql, django

What is the best practice for when to store constant values in a table vs a tuple.  For example, is it better to do this:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
  SOME_VALUES = (
   (0, 'A1'),
   (1, 'A2'),
   (2, 'A3'),
  )

  fieldA = models.IntegerField(choices=SOME_VALUES)
```

or have another model for the constant values:

```
class ConstantValue(models.Model):
  text = model.CharField(max_length=2)

class ModelA(models.Model):
  fieldA = models.OneToOneField(ConstantValue)
```

and a fixture would populate `ConstantValue`.

I have combination of the above in my code, but I'd like some consistency.

And what about many-to-many relationships?  I have a model with constants as above and another model that points to the constant model with a `ManyToManyField` relationship.  It's similar to the [Django tutorial's pizza example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships).  But I suppose I could have this:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
  TOPPINGS = (
   (0, 'Tomato'),
   (1, 'Peppers'),
   ...
  )

  topping = models.IntegerField(choices=TOPPINGS)

class Pizza(models.Model):
  topping = models.ForeignKey(Topping)
```

Comment: Will constants be added by users of the website?

Comment: No.  They are all predefined.

Comment: In that case hard-coding them is fine; no need to depend on the database for this.

Comment: I'm still debating this.  One issue I've found with hard-coding them is if you wanted to print the string in a query using either the ORM or a raw SQL query, you'd have to loop through the query set again to get the string from the number.

Answer (score 0):

i have a very basic answer:

Whenever your Domain is probaply changing, use another (domain_) table (or other class) like a pizzaname; if you dont see a chance for changing - like gender (m/f/dont know) keep it short, altough the gender (of an entry) may change, the range wont (or most likely wont)